# Error on Virtual machine Bluemix connection

Tags: ibm-cloud

I do not get connection with this VM: `ssh ibmcloud@129.41.147.70`

> ssh: connect to host 129.41.147.70 port 22: Network is unreachable

Could it be that firewall rules now prevent me to connect to
`129.41.147.70`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify the ssh key, like:

ssh -i your_public_key ibmcloud@129.41.147.70

Also, check if the VM is runnning in the Bluemix UI and if you can ping the server from your machine.

Actually if you can ping it, it is likely a firewall issue with the error you are seeing.